# Recover internal data from a working phone but with broken screen, no developer mode and locked

Tags: screen

I don't know if this is the right SO community to ask this.

I have a Samsung Galaxy with the screen BROKEN, but just the screen, not the mobile.

I'd like just to EXTRACT all data from internal memory.

We have tried a lot of softwares and solutions from Internet forums, but all of them requires DEVELOPER MODE or the device UNLOCKED.

I don't have DEVELOPER MODE on, and I can't unlock because I see nothing in the screen. Even we tried to plug an external mouse and try to click (blindly) in the numbers to pass the PIN screen. (The mobile works, because it vibrates after power on.)

Is the any solution to recover internal data?

It does not matter if I need to OPEN the phone, I will trash it after recovering, I don't need it to be operative again, I just need the internal data.

Comment: I've voted to migrate this to android, where it would be a better fit, but basically, the entire point of having an encrypted hardware device is so you can't force your way in ...

Comment: Which model is your device? You can flash modified boot image which has ADB enabled

Comment: samsung j510 ... how can I do that esQmo_ ?  remember screen is completely broken :-P

Comment: You need ADB for such situations. Did you enabled USB Debugging?

Comment: As I described, developer mode is not enabled in the phone. The device is LOCKED (when it starts, so I can not put the PIN code, therefore I can not transfer files) and DEVELOPER MODE is off (therefore I can't use any of the popular methods to recover things)